# MUI X v6 `renderInput` alternative

Tags: material-ui

As `renderInput` is now removed from `<TimePicker>`, How can I show an error message with a TextField now?

Currently, I am using a code as followed:

```
renderInput={(params) => (
  <TextField
    {...params}
    sx={{ width: '100%' }}
    error
    helperText="Your error message" 
  />
)}
```

But how do I transform this code into MUI X v6?

I have tried using the new `componentProps` as stated in the new documentation, but it seems like it does not have as much customization allowed as old the renderInput way.

Comment: Does https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-pickers-v5/#input-renderer-required-in-v5 help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems your code can be reproduced with the `slotProps` (or the deprecated `componentsProps`).

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-43ql7s?file=/demo.tsx

```
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{ 
    textField: { 
      sx: { width: '100%' }, 
      error: true, 
      helperText: "Your error message"
    }
  }}
/>
```

Is their specific customization you are looking for?